# How can I access the members of XMVECTOR?

Tags: c++, directx

So I have been reading [these](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/microsoft.directx_sdk.comparison.xmvectorless%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) articles, and I find implementing them a trouble. Currently, all I am trying to do is add two vectors together, leaving my question more specifically this: How can I add specific members of two given vectors together? An example would be this:

```
XMVECTOR v1 = XMVectorSet(1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0);
XMVECTOR v2 = XMVectorSet(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
```

Then I would need to be able to lets say add v1's third member (3.0) and v2's second member (1.0). How can I pull this off? I tried using:

```
v1.z += v2.x;
```

To no avail. Any help is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

DirectXMath's `XMVECTOR` is an opaque platform-optimal type that you can only manipulate via free functions, on x86 something akin to a `_m128`.

You can set/get individual elements with functions like `XMVectorSetZ`, but note that this is cumbersome for a reason, as such non-wide operations are likely to be more expensive than expected on SIMD types.

If you want a more traditional CPU-friendly type for extensive non-SIMD work, consider `XMFLOAT4` as it's more of a "struct of four floats" which you seem to desire.

You can always roundtrip between the types based on local needs with `XMLoadFloat4` and `XMStoreFloat4`.

Answer (score 2):

You don't access the vector's members directly, you have to copy the vector to a XMFLOAT4 first:

```
XMVECTOR v2 = XMVectorSet(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
XMFLOAT4 v2F;    //the float where we copy the v2 vector members
XMStoreFloat4(&v2F, v2);   //the function used to copy
```

now you can access and manipulate the v2F members simply like so:

```
v2F.x = 4.5f;
```

when you are done, just copy back the v2F to v2:

```
v2 = XMLoadFloat4(&v2F);
```